# Change color of text when button is pushed?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I know how to change the background color but what about the actual text? There doesn't seem to be a member on a UIButton called "color" or anything like that. 
My code:

```
@IBAction func yellowBtnClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        gameboard.image = UIImage(named: "Yellow_gb")
        resultsView.image = UIImage(named: "Yellow_results")
        colorsView.image = UIImage(named: "Yellow_colors")
        colorsBtn.color = UIColor.brownColor() //This line has the issue

    }
```

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There is no property setter `color` in `UIButton`. use instead `setTitleColor`.Write this in `viewWillAppear`

```
colorsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.brownColor(), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

This will change title color to brown for `UIControlState.Normal`

To set the color of `title` when button is in `Highlighted` state use

```
colorsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.brownColor(), forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
```

Answer (score 6):

Swift 3.0 example:

```
    colorsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor .white, for: UIControlState.normal)
    colorsBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor .black, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
```